# gh pr diff - could not determine acurrent branch: failed to run git: not on any branch

Tags: github-actions

I'm running actions to get the file names changed in the PR, but I get the message:

> could not determine current branch: failed to run git: not on any branch

```
    - name: Checkout commit
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Get files
      env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
      run: |
          echo "Files for this PR:"
          gh pr diff --name-only | xargs find 2> /dev/null | cat
```

I was checking different options, but I cannot find what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you missed to PR's branch name (the checkout job doesn't do it).

Something like this could help:

```
      # Only used because Github CLI needs to be in a repo apparently
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Get files
        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
          BRANCH: ${{ github.head_ref }}
        run: |
          echo "Files for this PR:"
          gh pr diff "$BRANCH" --name-only
```

Answer (score 0):

After several tries I found solution without using gh cli.

```
- name: Checkout code
  uses: actions/checkout@v4
  with:
      fetch-depth: 2

- name: Get files
  env:
      GH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
  run: |
      echo "Files for this PR:"
      git diff --name-only -r HEAD^1 HEAD | xargs find 2> /dev/null | cat
```